# MySQL insert/update a row containing a point type using a prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, point, on-duplicate-key

I am using a prepared statement to try to insert a new row into the MySQL table and if the index exists perform an update. I am fairly sure that the issue is related to the "point" field labelled "grp_hall_geoPoint". I am receiving the error:

```
"SQLException in updateGroup: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET grp_country='Australia', grp_state='New South Wales', grp_region='Sydney Nor' at line 1"
```

The values being passed are:

```
public static void updateGroup(String state,
            String region, String district, String group, String section,
            String subSection, String archiveDate, String latitude, String longditude, String nas) {[/code]
```

The prepared statement is:

```
String insertUpdateQry = ("INSERT INTO at_group " +
                    "(grp_country, grp_state, grp_region, grp_district, grp_name, " +
                        " grp_section, grp_sub_section, grp_archived, grp_hall_geoPoint, grp_nas) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ?, ' ', ?, ')')), ?)" +
                    "ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
                    "UPDATE at_group " +
                      "SET grp_country=?, grp_state=?, grp_region=?, grp_district=?, " +
                      "grp_name=?, grp_section=?, grp_sub_section=?, grp_archived=?, " +
                      "grp_hall_geoPoint=PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ?, ' ', ?, ')')), grp_nas=?;");

            try {
                // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
                c = ds.getConnection();
                ps = c.prepareStatement(insertUpdateQry);

                try {
                    // Create a statement and execute the query on it
                    ps.setString(1, "Australia");
                    ps.setString(2, state);
                    ps.setString(3, region);
                    ps.setString(4, district);
                    ps.setString(5, group);
                    ps.setString(6, section);
                    ps.setString(7, subSection);
                    ps.setString(8, archiveDate);
                    ps.setString(9, latitude);
                    ps.setString(10, longditude);
                    ps.setString(11, nas);

                    ps.setString(12, "Australia");
                    ps.setString(13, state);
                    ps.setString(14, region);
                    ps.setString(15, district);
                    ps.setString(16, group);
                    ps.setString(17, section);
                    ps.setString(18, subSection);
                    ps.setString(19, archiveDate);
                    ps.setString(20, latitude);
                    ps.setString(21, longditude);
                    ps.setString(22, nas);

                    ps.executeUpdate();
```

The following are in a unique index: grp_country, grp_state, grp_region, grp_district, grp_name, grp_section, grp_sub_section

grp_hall_geoPoint is type point

I have used test data to trigger the update and insert with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this query to (have removed table name and set statement):

Reference here:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

```
String insertUpdateQry = ("INSERT INTO at_group " +
                    "(grp_country, grp_state, grp_region, grp_district, grp_group, " +
                        " grp_section, grp_sub_section, grp_archived, grp_hall_geoPoint, grp_nas) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ?, ' ', ?, ')')), ?)" +
                    "ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
                    "UPDATE " +
                      "grp_country=?, grp_state=?, grp_region=?, grp_district=?, " +
                      "grp_name=?, grp_section=?, grp_sub_section=?, grp_archived=?, " +
                      "grp_hall_geoPoint=PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ?, ' ', ?, ')')), grp_nas=?;");
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error does not have anything to do with the point data type. You must not provide the table name and `set` after `update` in the `on duplicate key update` clause.

So, instead of

```
...
"ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
"UPDATE at_group " +
"SET grp_country=?, ...
```

You need to simply write:

```
...
"ON DUPLICATE KEY " +
"UPDATE grp_country=?, ...
```